# How can I create a self signed certificate?

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, self-signed-certificate

I create a self signed certificate with powershell in my server.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

I go on **mmc** :

```
File -> Add or Remove Snap-ins -> Certificates -> Add -> Computer account -> Local computer
```

I expand the Personal folder and you see my localhost certificate

I copy and paste it into `Trusted Root Certification Authorities - Certificates`

After that I bind my application on IIS :

[image: binding]

But I still have the error :

[image: error]

How can I resolve my issue ? Or maybe there an other free solution.

Comment: The error message is completely justified. Since its not a "proper" certificate, there is no trusted third party to check the certificate and identity against.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Ok thank you there is an other free solution ? or I will always have this message ?

Comment: Check out LetsEncrypt :)

Comment: @I.TDelinquent - installing the certificate into the Trusted Root CAs folder on the client machine should *normally* make it trusted. I've always found it to be a bit of a dark art though, but It definitely works with a self-signed certificate if things are set up properly.

Comment: @user10863293 - are you using the browser to access the site on the same machine as where you've installed the certificate? What hostname did you create the certificate for, and what url are you using to browse the site?

Comment: @mclayton I use a remote desktop connection to access to the server. So I'm not in the same machine. My hostname is localhost abd the url I use is https://[server_name]:3002

Comment: localhost is just an alias for the local machine. You're going to have to use whatever hostname is in the URL

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I try an other hostname it doesn't work

Comment: Some background, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Comment: open iis manager select site from the server node, then select browse from the action node with the https binding.[image1](https://imgur.com/NUKhktZ) and [image2](https://imgur.com/a/lQc3Yt9)

Answer (score 2):

The following commands in PowerShell (when run as admin) will do the trick:

1. We create a new root trusted cert:

   ```
   $rootCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=TestRootCA,O=TestRootCA,OU=TestRootCA' -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeyUsage CertSign,CRLSign,DigitalSignature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyUsageProperty All -KeyAlgorithm 'RSA' -HashAlgorithm 'SHA256'  -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider'
   ```
2. We create the cert from the root trusted cert chain:

   ```
   New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Signer $rootCert -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") -Provider "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" -HashAlgorithm "SHA256"
   ```
3. We copy the thumbprint returned by the last command
4. (If necessary) We remove the last association ip/port/cert:

   ```
   netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:3002
   ```
5. We associate the new certificate with any ip and your port, 3002 in your case (the appid value is any valid guid):

   ```
   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:3002 appid='{214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a}' certhash=here_the_copied_thumbprint
   ```
6. Now, you must drag and drop the TestRootCA from Personal/Certificates folder to Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates.

These commands also resolve the **ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM** error returned by Google Chrome because the certificate is created with the SHA256 algorithm instead of SHA1.

Comment: After following countless tutorials, this is the one that worked for me!  That was insanely difficult to figure out!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the certificate to both Personal and Trusted Root Authorities. To set up a self signed with Powershell for IIS the functions below should help you out.

Run the script as administrator - if you are on Windows 10 chances are that you must install module WebAdministration.

```
#Install-Module -Name 'WebAdministration'

Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

function AddSelfSignedCertificateToSSL([String]$dnsname, [String]$siteName='Default Web Site'){
 $newCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $dnsname -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
 $binding = Get-WebBinding -Name $siteName -Protocol "https"
 $binding.AddSslCertificate($newCert.GetCertHashString(), "My")
 $newCertThumbprint = $newCert.Thumbprint
 $sourceCertificate = $('cert:\localmachine\my\' + $newCertThumbprint)

 $store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "Root", LocalMachine
 $store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
 $store.Add($newCert)
 return $newCertThumbprint
}

Write-Host Installing self-signed certificate Cert:\LocalMachine\My and Cert:\LocalMachine\Root ..

$certinstalledThumbprint = AddSelfSignedCertificateToSSL 'someacmeapp.somedomain.net'

Write-Host Added certificate $certinstalledThumbprint to Cert:\LocalMachine\My and Cert:\LocalMachine\Root and set this up as the SSL certificate on Default Web Site.
```

Note that modern browsers such as Chrome will complain about weak algorithms used in self signed algorithm and the fact that there is no third-party certificate authority such as GoDaddy et cetera that can confirm the validity certificate since it is self signed and has a weak algorithm.